# Exclude some elements from ajax process

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2

I have a form with a lot of elements. Inside this form there is a commandButton, which fires an ajax request to the server and updates the entire form.

But there is one or two elements that I don't want to process in this ajax event. How can I exclude only this components from processing, like, "process all the form elements but not this components", instead of specifying all the components to process?

Answer (score 0):

for example you can call a js function with command button and capture all the elements that you wanna send. ex:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            <!--
                function call(a, b, c, d...) {
                    addDocument(a);
                                    .....
                }

            --> 
            </script>
        <a4j:jsFunction name="addDocument" action="addDocument" reRender="panellImatge" 
                 ajaxSingle="true">
            <a4j:actionparam name="idDocument"
                    assignTo="#{crearUsuarisBB.newDocumentId}" />
        </a4j:jsFunction>
```

and in command button call --Call();

I hope it helps.